# I have compiled my cpp code to generate a dll file in visual studio, but I cannot find the generated dll file. Is there any default name for dll in vs

Tags: c++, visual-studio, java-native-interface

The code compiled:

```
#include <jni.h> // JNI header provided by JDK
#include <iostream>    // C++ standard IO header
#include "HelloJNI.h"  // Generated
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// Implementation of the native method sayHello()
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv* env, jobject thisObj)
{
    cout << "Narain C A";
}

int main() {
    JNIEXPORT void Java_HelloJNI_sayHello();
}
```

How to find the generated dll file in visual studio?

Comment: I guess it's stored in `"project path\x64\Debug"` or `"project path\x64\Release"` and it's name is the project name. I'm not very familiar with DLLs so not sure about this one.

Comment: There are exe,lib,pdb,exp files in the folder but i could not able to find a file with dll extension

Comment: For my machine, there is a file with the extension. You can try making a new project and compiling the default code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the output directory macros in Properties.
[image]

Comment: Also I haven't changed my config type to .dll now it worked